# Adding vertical lines to each side of a paragraph

Tags: paragraphs, text-decorations

How can I add vertical lines to each side of a paragraph?

To illustrate, what I need is:

```
 some paragraphs...

|My paragraph begins|
|here and goes like |
|this... ~~~~~~~~~~~|
|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|
|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|
|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|
|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|
--------------------- <- Here is a page break
|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|
|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|
|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|
|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|
|The paragraph ends |
|here.              |

Some other paragraphs...
```

I could not use any tabular or boxing commands since they don't allow page breaks inside.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: do you want the vertical lines in the margin or as in Gonzalo's answer inside the text area?

Comment: @jfbu my answer now includes both options.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newmdenv[
  topline=false,
  bottomline=false,
  skipabove=\topsep,
  skipbelow=\topsep
]{siderules}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{siderules}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{siderules}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a simplemodification placing the rules in the margin (now the text width inside the environment is equal to the default \textwidth):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newmdenv[
  topline=false,
  bottomline=false,
  skipabove=\topsep,
  skipbelow=\topsep,
  leftmargin=-10pt,
  rightmargin=-10pt,
  innertopmargin=0pt,
  innerbottommargin=0pt
]{siderules}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{siderules}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{siderules}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the first paragraphs in both cases are not indented, is this an after-effect of the use of `mdframed`?

Comment: @jfbu yes, apparently the first line of the first paragraph is not indented by design.

Comment: @jfbu to get the first line indented, one can add `\mbox{}\indent` right after `\begin{siderules}`.

Comment: That's what I was really looking for. Thank you so much..

Comment: This solution changed where my footnotes appeared

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I fond that margin setting is inhibited by the use of [memoir] class. Is there any way to use the full potential of this package in [memoir] class?

Comment: does not seem to be compatible with footnotes

Comment: If there is one footnote use \footnotemark and \footnotetext. With multiple footnotes use \footnotetext[number] to fix the numbering of the footnotes

Answer (score 12):

With results similar to Gonzalo's answer but made with [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{tcbsiderules}[1][]{blanker, breakable, 
     left=3mm, right=3mm, top=1mm, bottom=1mm,
     borderline vertical={1pt}{0pt}{black},
     before upper=\indent, parbox=false, #1}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{tcbsiderules}[oversize]
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{tcbsiderules}
\begin{tcbsiderules}
\lipsum[5-7]
\end{tcbsiderules}
\lipsum[8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get the error: `I do not know the key '/tcp/borderline vertical', to which you passed '{1pt}{0pt}{black}', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

Comment: @macmadness86 You need to update `tcolorbox`. According its documentation, `borderline vertical` was added on 20-Oct-2014.

Comment: Ok I see. I will probably not be able to use your option then, because I unfortunately cannot update the system (yet). Thanks for identifying the problem though!

Comment: @macmadness86: If you don't want to update your system, just install `tcoorbox.sty` and `...code.tex` files from [ctan](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox) in your working folder. It's not the correct solution, but will work until you update the system.

Comment: more footnote friendly than mdframe, though it supercedes the footnote system by moving them at the end of the box (and thus uses a letter system to avoid confusions)