# Arrows line decoration on the left of paragraph

Tags: formatting, paragraphs

I'm working on a small package to manage QRH (a sort of checklist for aeronautical purposes). I want to print a line with arrows on the left of the paragraph, possibly with text in the middle, like in the figure:

[image: arrows]

Currently I'm using `siderules` of `mdframed` package, as [suggested here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86381/adding-vertical-lines-to-each-side-of-a-paragraph/86389#86389), but I'm able to produce only a straight vertical line, without arrows and without text.

Anyone has some idea? :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`tikzmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) could be one option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[\tikzmark{a}Blabla text here:] \lipsum[1]
\item[\tikzmark{b}Blabla text here:] \lipsum[1]
\end{description}

\tikz[remember picture,<->] \draw[overlay] ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:a) --++(-0.5,0)  |- ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:b) node[midway, pos=0.25, fill=white]{text};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here I use a macro approach, `\connect{text}{lines}`, where lines is the multiple of baselineskip to the connecting line.  It can be a non-integer if there are added vertical spaces to contend with (e.g., `\topskip` and such).

Because the decoration is employed using the `tabto` package, the `\connect{}{}` macro can be issued at any place on the starting line of the connection.

EDITED to handle negative `<lines>` argument, which can reach upward.  This can be useful to connect to display math, for which `\connect` is not valid.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,tabto}
\newlength\tmplen
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\newcommand\connect[2]{%
  \setstackgap{S}{0pt}%
  \tabto*{0in}%
  \setlength\tmplen{\dimexpr#2\baselineskip-\baselineskip}%
  \setlength\tmplen{.5\tmplen}%
  \ifdim\tmplen>0pt\relax
  \smash{\raisebox{2.5pt}{\makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \Shortunderstack[l]{%
      \smash{\raisebox{-2.7pt}{\rarrow}}\cr
      \protect\rule{.5pt}{\tmplen}\cr
      \makebox[0pt]{#1\strut}\cr
      \protect\rule{.5pt}{\tmplen}%
      \smash{\raisebox{-2.4pt}{\rarrow}}\cr
    }%
  }}}%
  \else
    \setlength\tmplen{-\tmplen}%
    \smash{\raisebox{2.5pt}{\makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \Shortstack[l]{%
      \smash{\raisebox{-2.7pt}{\rarrow}}\cr
      \protect\rule{.5pt}{\tmplen}\cr
      \makebox[0pt]{#1\strut}\cr
      \protect\rule{.5pt}{\tmplen}%
      \smash{\raisebox{-2.4pt}{\rarrow}}\cr
    }%
  }}}%
  \fi
  \tabto{\TabPrevPos}%
}
\def\rarrow{$\kern-.7pt{-}\kern-2pt{-}\kern-2pt{\rightarrow}$}
\begin{document}
\noindent\connect{OR}{4}\textbf{Blabla text here}\par
   Blabla text here\par
   Blabla text here\par
   Blabla text here\par
\noindent\textbf{Blabla text here}\par
   Blabla text here\par
   Blabla text here\par
   Blabla text here\par
\noindent\connect{AND}{6}\textbf{Blabla text here}\par
   Blabla text here\par
   Blabla text here\par
   Blabla text here\par
   Blabla text here\par
   Blabla text here\par
\noindent\textbf{Blabla text here}\par
   Blabla text here\par
   Blabla text here\par
   Blabla text here\par
   Blabla text here\par
   Blabla text here\par
   Blabla text here\par
\[
  y = mx + b
\]
   Blabla text here\par
   Blabla text here\par
   \noindent \connect{Math!}{-1.8}Blabla text here\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is super cool. Is there any way how this could work with equations?

Comment: @JakobH I don't believe that `tabto` works in display math.  The closest I could come (for unnumbered display math) is `Blabla text here\par
\medskip
  \connect{Hmm}{3.5}\centerline{$y = mx + b$}\par
\medskip
   Blabla text here\par
   Blabla text here\par
   Blabla text here\par`

Comment: @JakobH See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263480/undersetting-an-arrow-beneath-an-equation/263491#263491

Comment: @JakobH See my edit.  You cannot use `\connect` in display math, but you can backward connect to it with the use of a negative argument for the 2nd argument of `\connect`.