# Letters or numbers as tikz nodes

Tags: tikz-arrows

Is it possible to draw an tikz arc (arrow) between to letters (numbers) in a Latex document? If yes, how to define the nodes in that case?

Comment: I don't understand, whether a TikZ node contains a number or a letter, the way you define it is exactly the same.

Comment: Assuming that you want to connect arbitray characters in the page via a overlayed arc, the answer would be to use `\tikzmark` command to mark the characters and tikz's `remember picture, overlay` options to draw connections between them. See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242068/arrows-line-decoration-on-the-left-of-paragraph) for example. The details depend on what you specifically want to do.

Comment: I have few listings with \lstlisting and I need arrows that point from one line of the code to the other.

Answer (score 3):

The general approach to add graphics on top of already typeset text in the page is to use TikZ `remember picture` and `overlay` options. An invisible tikz node can be placed next to the points of interest, so that the point receives a name, and then another tikzpicture draws connections between those nodes.

Andrew Stacey had this idea of adding invisible nodes to mark points in the page, called them "tizkmarks", and wrote the [tikzmark](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) package.

In your case, since you aim is to draw on top of code listings (as expressed in a comment after the question), it gets a bit more complex, because inside a listing environment you cannot enter latex commands (and thus `\tikzmark`) without escaping them somehow.

Depending on the language you use in your code listings, an easy way could be to use the option `mathescape`, which allows the use of the dollar sign inside the listings to escape to math mode. Once in math mode you can use `\tikzmark`. However, if your listings are PHP or Perl scripts, in which the dollar appears frequently, this approach is not valid. You can use `escapechar` to choose another special character to escape to latex.

The following example uses `mathescape` to enter latex in the listings, and put the tikz marks, and then, after the listing, a `tikzpicture` draws a cuved arrow between these marks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \coordinate (#1) {};}
\begin{document}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02},
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}\itshape,
    backgroundcolor=\color[RGB]{248,248,248},
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    linewidth=\textwidth,
    basewidth=0.5em,
    mathescape,
}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char who="world";

  printf("Hello %$\tikzmark{s}$s\n", who$\tikzmark{who}$);
  return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[red, ->, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt] 
        (who) to[bend left] node[midway, below] {replaces} (s);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image: Result]

Note that this approach can fail if the listing is inside a float, because this can lead to the listing to appear in a different page than the annotated arrow. In this case you have to put the `tikzpicture` inside the same float than the listing. This would require to use the `escapeinside` option of `listings`, to define two chars to delimite a block of latex code inside the `lstlistings` environment.

Comment: This is more or less what I wanted, but from one line of code to another. I managed to do that by changing the position of the nodes. How can I 'curve' the arrow a little more?