# tcolorbox does not break and starts on next page

Tags: tcolorbox, boxes, book-design, frame

I'm a beginner with latex and would have liked to make a recipe book. Each recipe would be framed in a tcolorbox as shown on the screenshot below:

[image: example of a recipe frame]

The problem is that the boxes don't break if there isn't enough place for the complete box on the page. For an example, see this page:

[image]

What I would like to obtain is something like this (I arranged the previous picture with Gimp):

[image]

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{indentfirst} %package qui sert à avoir un alinéa au premier paragraphe de chaque section

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage[skins, many]{tcolorbox}  %[skins, many]
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist  %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-change-the-margins-for-only-part-of-the-text

\newmdenv[
  topline=false,
  bottomline=false,
  rightline=false,
  linewidth=1.5pt,
  skipabove=\topsep,
  skipbelow=\topsep
]{siderules}   %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86381/adding-vertical-lines-to-each-side-of-a-paragraph

\newtcolorbox{ficherecette}{enhanced jigsaw, colback=white, enforce breakable, nobeforeafter}

\newcommand{\nomrecette}[1]{\newpage \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}\begin{center} \begin{Large} \textbf{#1} \end{Large} \end{center}}

\newcommand{\descriptionrecette}[1]{\hspace{1cm} \textit{#1}\\}

%\newcommand{\infosrecette}[4]{\\\textbf{Informations pratiques~:}\begin{itemize} \item[•] Nombres de personnes~: #1 \item[•] Préparation~: #2 minutes \item[•] Cuisson~: #3 minutes \item[•] Repos~: #4 minutes\\ \end{itemize}}

\newcommand{\infosrecette}{\\\textbf{Informations pratiques~:}\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\quantite}[1]{\item[•] Quantité~: #1} %/!\ajouter l'unité
\newcommand{\tpsprepa}[1]{\item[•] Temps de préparation~: #1 minutes}
\newcommand{\tpsprepassmin}[1]{\item[•] Temps de préparation~: #1} %tps e prépa sans minutes. ex.: rapide
\newcommand{\tpscuisson}[1]{\item[•] Cuisson~: #1 minutes}
\newcommand{\tpsrepos}[1]{\item[•] Repos~: #1}
\newcommand{\fininfosrecette}{\\ \end{itemize}}

\newcommand{\ingredients}{\textbf{Ingrédients~:} \begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\itemingredient}[1]{\item[•] #1}
\newcommand{\finingredients}{\\\end{itemize}}

\newcommand{\matos}{\textbf{Matériel spécifique~:} \begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\itemmatos}[1]{\item[•] #1}
\newcommand{\finmatos}{\\\end{itemize}}

\newcommand{\conseil}[1]{\end{itemize}\begin{changemargin}{2cm}{2cm} \begin{siderules}\begin{minipage}{11.7cm}\textit{\textbf{Conseil pratique~:} #1}\end{minipage}\end{siderules}\end{changemargin}\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\dernierconseil}[1]{\end{itemize}\begin{changemargin}{2cm}{2cm} \begin{siderules}\begin{minipage}{11.7cm}\textit{\textbf{Conseil pratique~:} #1}\end{minipage}\end{siderules}\end{changemargin}}
\newcounter{compteuretapes}
\newcommand{\etapes}{\textbf{Préparation~:}\setcounter{compteuretapes}{1}\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\itemetape}[1]{\item[\textbf{\arabic{compteuretapes}.}] #1\stepcounter{compteuretapes}}
\newcommand{\finetapes}{\end{itemize}}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\title{My recipe book}
\author{Myself}
\date{2023}
\clearpage\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Entrées}
\chapter{Soupes}
\chapter{Plats principaux}
\chapter{Desserts}
\begin{ficherecette}
\nomrecette{Pudding à la vanille}
\descriptionrecette{Pudding traditionnel transmit de mère en fille...}
\infosrecette{}
\quantite{5 ramequins et 3 mini-ramequins}
\tpsprepa{15}
\tpscuisson{10}
\tpsrepos{le temps que ça refroidisse à notre goût}
\fininfosrecette{}
\ingredients{}
\itemingredient{1 l de lait}
\itemingredient{55 g de sucre}
\itemingredient{60 g de pudding-powder}
\finingredients{}
\etapes{}
\itemetape{Dans une casserole, mélanger le sucre avec le lait et la poudre de pudding.}
\conseil{Au four à micro-ondes ? Mélanger les ingrédients dans un bol prévu à cet effet.}
\itemetape{Faire bouillir le lait pendant au minimum 1~min.}
\conseil{Au four à micro-ondes ? Programmer 10~min à 1000~W en retirant 3 fois ou plus pour remuer.}
\itemetape{Verser immédiatement dans les bols.}
\finetapes{}
\end{ficherecette}
\begin{ficherecette}
\nomrecette{Pudding à la vanille}
\descriptionrecette{Pudding traditionnel transmit de mère en fille...}
\infosrecette{}
\quantite{5 ramequins et 3 mini-ramequins}
\tpsprepa{15}
\tpscuisson{10}
\tpsrepos{le temps que ça refroidisse à notre goût}
\fininfosrecette{}
\ingredients{}
\itemingredient{1 l de lait}
\itemingredient{55 g de sucre}
\itemingredient{60 g de pudding-powder}
\finingredients{}
\etapes{}
\itemetape{Dans une casserole, mélanger le sucre avec le lait et la poudre de pudding.}
\conseil{Au four à micro-ondes ? Mélanger les ingrédients dans un bol prévu à cet effet.}
\itemetape{Faire bouillir le lait pendant au minimum 1~min.}
\conseil{Au four à micro-ondes ? Programmer 10~min à 1000~W en retirant 3 fois ou plus pour remuer.}
\itemetape{Verser immédiatement dans les bols.}
\finetapes{}
\end{ficherecette}
\begin{ficherecette}
\nomrecette{Pudding à la vanille}
\descriptionrecette{Pudding traditionnel transmit de mère en fille...}
\infosrecette{}
\quantite{5 ramequins et 3 mini-ramequins}
\tpsprepa{15}
\tpscuisson{10}
\tpsrepos{le temps que ça refroidisse à notre goût}
\fininfosrecette{}
\ingredients{}
\itemingredient{1 l de lait}
\itemingredient{55 g de sucre}
\itemingredient{60 g de pudding-powder}
\finingredients{}
\etapes{}
\itemetape{Dans une casserole, mélanger le sucre avec le lait et la poudre de pudding.}
\conseil{Au four à micro-ondes ? Mélanger les ingrédients dans un bol prévu à cet effet.}
\itemetape{Faire bouillir le lait pendant au minimum 1~min.}
\conseil{Au four à micro-ondes ? Programmer 10~min à 1000~W en retirant 3 fois ou plus pour remuer.}
\itemetape{Verser immédiatement dans les bols.}
\finetapes{}
\end{ficherecette}
\end{document}
```

I tried the breakable option on my tcolorbox but it doesn't work... I also saw this post [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319355/tcolorbox-breakable-option-not-working] but I didn't understand how it has been resolved and I'm not shure it's the same problem as mine.

Can somebody please help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just remove the `\newpage` at beginning of definition of `\nomrecette`. You may also want to remove `nobeforeafter` from `\newtcolorbox{ficherecette}{...}` and set proper before/after skip.

Comment: Thanks, it works pretty well!!!