# Add Fingerprint-like markings accompanying text

Tags: pdftex

I am working on a longer document with different reliabilities of the sources. At first, I wanted to change the font color to indicate the different levels (red - low, yellow - medium, green - high confidence). Not surprisingly, this made the text colorful and less readable. A second idea was to change the background of the text, offering a bit more readability, but it is still more hindering than useful.

Now, I would like to add a fingerprint-like visualization/marking next to the text. The confidence of the text is given rather on a paragraph than a sentence level, hence, little inaccuracies are not an issue.

Please consider this very professional sketch of how I would imagine it:
[image]

Since my LaTeX experience with anything other than "standard texts" is quite low, I am not even sure how to begin with trying something like this. Especially when I need to somehow "sync" between both parts. My first idea here was to use minipages, but then I had no idea how to indicate up to which height the "red part" should go.
Right now, the document has 50 pages and I expect it to double its number of pages until I am finished and about 90% of them will need such a marking. Therefore, a method that does not require any kind of pixel values or much manual correction would be great.

I am very open to other useful ideas of how to indicate "levels" of the text passages visually, without hindering readability.
Just now, I had the idea that it may be easier to color the first (few pixels?) part of each line with the "current" color, which may be easier.

Thanks a lot for your ideas and help,

Raubwurst

PS: If useful/needed: I am mainly working with overleaf

Update: After using the great solution by Sandy G., I have an issue with footnotes. They appear on the end of the enclosed text block, but no longer on the footer of the page. I use the (standard) \footnote{}
[image]

Comment: Welcome. // The easist thing to do would be using `\marginpar{}` . Place as text e.g. usefül symbols from fontawesome (see https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) , or short colored objects, e.g. by using `\tikz{}` as "text".

Comment: The [`changebar` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/changebar) comes into mind. Not sure if this is applicable here.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86381/adding-vertical-lines-to-each-side-of-a-paragraph could help

Comment: Better to ask a new question and link to this one. But also, see the comment by @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possibility using `tcolorbox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable}

\newtcolorbox{fprint}[1]{%
blankest, breakable,
before upper={\parindent15pt},
beforeafter skip balanced=0.2\baselineskip plus 2pt,
borderline west={8mm}{-20mm}{#1}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{fprint}{red}
\lipsum[3]
\end{fprint}

\begin{fprint}{yellow}
\lipsum[4]
\end{fprint}

\begin{fprint}{green}
\lipsum[5]
\end{fprint}

\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly how I imagined it :)

Comment: Update: It seems like this approach has issues with footnotes, which are no longer on the footer of the page, but after the enclosed text block. I updated my initial post with a screenshot, where the footnotes are followed by two lines of text from another colored fprint

Comment: @Raubwurst `\usepackage{footnote}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{fprint}{\savenotes}
\AfterEndEnvironment{fprint}{\spewnotes}`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you :3 All of you are awesome!

Comment: @Raubwurst You're welcome! Have fun with @ SandyG's great answers!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example using `\marginpar`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}
 \marginpar{\warning}\lipsum[1-2]
 
 For some embedding \dots \marginpar{\leafNE\leafNE\leafNE}\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!